# Properties of Hilbert Spaces- Contrasting Two Different Topological Spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compactness

Let H be the space of real sequences **x** = $(x_1 , x_2, ... )$ with $\sum(x_n^2)$ finite. (This is $l_2$ in fact.) I wish to show the following:

The topology on H is different from the topology it would inherit as a subspace of R (the reals) raised to the power of aleph-null, $\aleph_0$.

Anything with this regard will definitely help, as I am not sure how to begin.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: The unit ball in a Hilbert space is compact if and only if the space is finite dimensional.